# How to write multiple "or" conditions in the dplyr - if_else?

Tags: r, dplyr

This might be basic. Consider a data frame:

```
df<-data.frame(year=c(2006:2015),
               one=rep(2010,10),
               two=rep(2011,10),
               three=rep(2012,10))
```

where `one` is the year that Event One occurred, `two` is the year that Event Two occurred, and `three` is the year that Event Three occurred. I want to construct a variable `ha`, which takes the value 1 if it has been at most 2 years since either of these events occurred, and 0 if otherwise.

For example, in 2009, neither of these events occurred, so `ha` for 2009 should be 0. In 2015, it has been 3 years since Event Three occurred and 5 years since Event One occurred, so `ha` should be 0. But in 2011, Event One occurred last year and Event Two just occurred, so `ha` for 2011 should be 1.

The ending result should look like this for `ha`:

```
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0
```

However, when I try to use `if_else` in dplyr to evaluate multiple "or" conditions, I failed to get the desired result. Here is my code:

```
df<-df%>%
  mutate(
    ha=if_else(year-one%in%c(0,1,2)|year-two%in%c(0,1,2)|year-three%in%c(0,1,2),1,0)
  )
```

I wonder where my mistake is.

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is precedence. The `%in%` gets evaluated first, so it calculated `one%in%c(0,1,2)` instead of `year-one%in%c(0,1,2)`. The solution is to wrap parentheses around `year - one`:

```r
df%>%
  mutate(
    ha=if_else((year-one)%in%c(0,1,2)|(year-two)%in%c(0,1,2)|(year-three)%in%c(0,1,2),1,0)
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

in base R

```
a <- df[,1] - df[-1] 
df$ha <- +(rowSums(a >=0 & a<=2)>0)
df
   year  one  two three ha
1  2006 2010 2011  2012  0
2  2007 2010 2011  2012  0
3  2008 2010 2011  2012  0
4  2009 2010 2011  2012  0
5  2010 2010 2011  2012  1
6  2011 2010 2011  2012  1
7  2012 2010 2011  2012  1
8  2013 2010 2011  2012  1
9  2014 2010 2011  2012  1
10 2015 2010 2011  2012  0
```

You could also use `apply`:

```
as.numeric(apply(a >= 0 & a <= 2, 1, any))
 [1] 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0
```

using `tidyverse`:

```
df %>%
  mutate(ha = +if_any(-year, ~ year - .x >= 0 & year -. x <= 2))

   year  one  two three ha
1  2006 2010 2011  2012  0
2  2007 2010 2011  2012  0
3  2008 2010 2011  2012  0
4  2009 2010 2011  2012  0
5  2010 2010 2011  2012  1
6  2011 2010 2011  2012  1
7  2012 2010 2011  2012  1
8  2013 2010 2011  2012  1
9  2014 2010 2011  2012  1
10 2015 2010 2011  2012  0
```